# Magento API SOAPv2: add bundle products to cart. Where to take options?

Tags: php, magento, soap, magento-1.7

there are already some questions on this subject, but only little parts and/or with partial solutions with few documentation.

I have basically a lot of doubts on how it works.

First of all: where to take the parameters for the associative array `bundle_option`? If I use the API call `catalogProductCustomOptionList` on my bundle, the result is an empty list even if in the bundle's details I clearly see `["has_options"]=> string(1) "1"`.

The other part of the question is, of course, on how to pass this options to the `shoppingCartProductAdd` API call.

The [documentation](https://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html) explains that it's an associative array, but how it has to be formed? There are some examples around, without explanations and/or not working.

I am able to get the options programmatically, but I need to interact with the server through its APIs.

Any hints to proceed?

*MAGENTO 1.7.0.2.*